# Reason for the development of First Order Logic and PDDL

Tags: logic, artificial-intelligence, pddl

This might be a naive question, but i am really interested to know why logic was developed to be used in AI. In particular, what was the need to develop first order logic and PDDL in AI, if we could do the programming using simple atomic representation of states? Again, I realize this is a really basic question!!

Comment: This question is highly related to [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510176/why-do-we-need-pddl-when-we-already-have-first-order-logic/7511451#7511451] by the same author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your question is about: why do we program/model on a first-order level instead of a propositional level? Simply because it is more concise.

You can make propositions like "All humans can think." with a first-order language and don't have to state "Alice can think. Bob can think. Carol can think. ...".

If you look at some PDDL planning problems from the IPC, there are sometimes ground versions that are formulated on a propositional level. And the files are much larger. You don't want to write those by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about PDDL, but first order logic was developed before computers ever were invented, so it wasn't for use in AI. It tells you what arguments are valid.